# Include day of week in Long Date in Workflow Email

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, workflow, sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

My workflow sends an email. CurrentItem:LongDate gives 16 October 2014. How can I get the day of the week inserted at the start?

I'm using SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Date formats are derived based on the regional settings. If you want date to be like **Thursday, June 21, 2013** then change the regional settings to **English(United States)**

You can make this change through site settings page.

Comment: Thanks, but is this the only way? I have users in US and UK.

Comment: Another option is to add a new calculated column to the list, the column will give you the day of week. Use formula `=TEXT(WEEKDAY([Date]),"dddd")`

Comment: spent a long time trying to work out why the longdate solution for working days did not work - only to finally read it's a shoddy MS setup that only provides the day with the US format of longdate. Been resigned to creating the calculated column suggestion above. This works really well so thanks for suggesting it Amal. MUCH appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to retrieve the current server time, including a three-letter week day, using the *Call HTTP Web Service* action:

Make a HTTP request to `[%Workflow Context:Current Site URL%]_api` then extract the `Date` header from the response headers using the *Get an Item from a Dictionary* action, with the path `Date/(0)`.

The date will be returned in the format **Wed, 18 May 2016 06:40:55 GMT**. Note that given the time zone is GMT, you may need to adjust or account for any offset in your workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Add a date column to the list item columns _d, add a calculated column to the same list `_dow` with formula `=TEXT(WEEKDAY([_d]),"dddd")`, then in your workflow Set Current Item _d to be your date you want the day of week from, then Set any variable to the Current Item _dow column and that should contain the day of the week.