# SharePoint 2010 workflow to send email only thursdays

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow

Please help I have a requirement to send a reminder email on Thursdays if the item has not been approved. How can I achieve this with SharePoint 2010 designer?? How do I define a Thursday?

thanks in advance

Comment: Why thursdays? This would send a reminder between 1 minute and one week. Sounds odd. Why not reminder after 5 working days?

Comment: @4rchit3ct this is a requirement, it must only be thursdays as there are processes that must be signed on thursdays. please assist.

Answer (score 0):

> To get a string representing day of week: Copy 2 characters from start
>   of `[Modified Date (as Long Date)]` output to Variable: DayOfWeek
>   (e.g. `Mo`, `Tu`, `We`, `Th`...) Then, if DayOfWeek = `Th` send an
>   email and pause (# of days depending on priority).

Reference: [The answer to the question: Sharepoint 2013 Workflow send email reminder based on priority and certain weekdays](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/173173/6382)

Comment: My long date returns this "16 January 2015" whereas I'm looking for "Thursday, 16 January 2015" then I can substring the date and get the day part only. I'm not sure how I can force it.

Comment: @Vusi85 See https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/118336/6382